# Cant create liferay 6.1 web service

Tags: web-services, liferay, axis

I try to develop simple web service to liferay 6.1. I follow such manuals as http://www.liferay.com/de/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Creating+Liferay+6+plugin+web+service
and  http://liferay-blogging.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-create-services-in-liferay.html

Portlet creates successfully, but service does not appear in /api/secure/axis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Portlet specific web services do not appear in /api/secure/axis, but can be found at /your-portlet/api/axis. Those web service URLs have changed in Liferay 6.1.